# How to stop the execution of DialogResult based on a condition?

Tags: winforms, validation

I'm having a issue with the following scenario on Windows Forms:

I created a Form with two buttons, each button have been assigned with the behaviour DialogResult OK and DialogResult Cancel, respectively.
But based on certain conditions, I need to stop the execution of the OK button. The problem is that if I just made a return like this:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Control control in tblTable.Controls)
        {
            if (control.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
            {
                 if (control.Text.Trim() == "")
                 {
                     control.Focus(); return;
                 }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

The dialog result keeps returning the OK answer to the parent form.

I need to stop the execution of the event and not return any answer until the user corrects the info on the form. In other words, the user should be taken back to the form to correct any missing or wrong data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I wouldn't use `DialogResult`s on buttons in this scenario. I only tend to set the `DialogResult` when there's only distinct options that do not require any additional logic (i.e. making a custom MessageBox).

What I would do is to just send the `DialogResult` yourself on success:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (allIsOK())
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't.  Windows UI design demands that the dialog closes when the user presses the Enter key and that the default button (OK) is marked.  The workaround is simple, just set the DialogResult to None.

Answer (score 9):

As Hans Passant mentions in an comment, just set the DialogResult to None!
Like this:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ValidationFailed())
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
        return;
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: On the next click then, it will always be None

Comment: @CRice: No it will not. On the next click the DialogResult of the form will again have been set to OK by the button since the button's DialogResult property is set to OK. (Perhaps you thought I meant setting the the DialogProperty och the button to None?)

Answer (score 1):

Consider tapping into the Forms's `Closing` event, and use the `Cancel` property of the event args to cancel form closing.

Here's a web page that discusses the idea; it's VB, but you'll get the idea:

http://www.vbinfozine.com/t_wfdlg.shtml

Answer (score 0):

In Case you have used DialogResult on a button in a child Form (Which is a dialog), and want to return to form with no dialog result use a function on the form_closing() event:

```
private void ChildForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (notValidated)
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```